# right shift key goes to desktop

Tags: keyboard

I have an imac running OS 10.8.2 with a bluetooth keyboard.  I have had it for about 8 weeks.  When I hit the right shift key, all the open windows run off the screen and I am looking at the desktop.  When I hit it again, the windows come back.  I have taken the batteries out of the keyboard and restored the keyboard shortcut defaults.   I don't have a trackpad and nothing seems stuck.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Is this setting enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I went and reset keyboard defaults, I verified it said F11 for mission control.
I then changed it to the problematic shift key saved it, then went back to change it to F11 and voila it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the mission control, go to shortcut and click in show desktop F11 and put right shift and next click again and select F11, Done.